# Video doesn't appear on Chrome or Brave, but appears on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to make this video appear on chrome, but this just doesn't work. No videos are showing up on chrome or brave at the moment, when I try to plug them in. However, they work on Safari pretty nicely. Why is that? What might be stopping this video to appear in Chrome?

```
<video playsinline="" loop="" muted="" autoplay="" style="background-image: url('');" data-wf-ignore="true" data-object-fit="cover">
  <source src="imgs/im/fin2.mp4" data-wf-ignore="true">
</video>
```

Comment: FYI: `playsinline`, `loop`, `muted` and `autoplay` are all Boolean attributes, so `=""` is unnecessary. Even setting it to `false` will not work. As stated on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video): *"To disable video autoplay, autoplay="false" will not work; the video will autoplay if the attribute is there in the <video> tag at all"*

Comment: Oh alright, that makes sense. Thanks! Btw do you know why the video might not be showing up on chrome?

Comment: Some browser espacially mobile prowers prevent tzhe autoplay of videos for the purpose of preventing misusage of mobile high speed traffic. There is nothing worse then visiting a website that instantly consumes all highspeed traffic for the entire month just to play a video that you wasn't interested in

Comment: Check the console if any errors/warnings appear

Comment: what system are you using? Increasingly browsers do not automatically play videos without some user interaction first.

Comment: @AHaworth I'm using iOS and in this website the video works perfectly fine on Chrome. I'm actually trying to copy their layout and stuff https://www.sundown-studio.com/

Comment: Look closely - they are embedding a vimeo video.